# Tab-switching is disabled after jQuery is introduced to the page

Tags: jquery, nuxt.js, swiper.js

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li v-if="list.product!=undefined" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#productSize">{{$t('detail.tab.productSize')}}</a>
    </li>
    <li v-if="list.relateLamp!=undefined" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#relate">{{$t('detail.tab.relate')}}</a>
    </li>
    <li v-if="list.light!=undefined" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#light">{{$t('detail.tab.light')}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>

 <swiper :options="swiperOption" ref="mySwiper">
     <swiper-slide v-for="(item,index) in list.imgList" :key="index">
          <img :src="getImg(item)" />
     </swiper-slide>
        <div class="swiper-pagination" slot="pagination"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev" slot="button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next" slot="button-next"></div>
 </swiper>
```

```
    data() {
        return {
            swiperOption: {
                pagination: {
                    el: '.swiper-pagination',
                    type: 'fraction',
                },
                loop: true,
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                },
            },
        };
    },
 mounted() {
        if (process.client) {
            $(function () {
                $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
            });
            $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).tab('show');
            });
        }
    },
```

I could have toggled a TAB like this, but after I introduced jquery to the page, clicking toggled a TAB didn't work.
The reason for this is that you use jqueryin on the page because I used swiperon this page, and when I tested it on the phone, the error was wrong, and the error was like this.`Cannot read property ‘$el' of undefined` After I solved this problem by introducing jquery, I tried to test the TAB and found that clicking didn't work.When I was testing in the production environment before, clicking TAB on the mobile phone would directly redirect to the home page because of the anchor point, so I wanted to test this problem on the mobile terminal in the development environment, but the problem described above occurred.Jquery was introduced to make this page work, but jquery made tabs unclickable

Comment: You should read the documentation of your swiper and use the Vue approach for this. jQuery is irrelevant here, and I don't even know if it supports the `.tab('show')` method anyway. Also, if you want to make some DOM manipulation, use a regular `document.querySelector` rather than import jQuery just for `$`, there is no pros only cons with this approach.

Comment: Otherwise, you can also check for questions [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnuxt%5D+swiper). Or filter it with the `vue` tag, there is quite a few answers there already.

Comment: @kissu The.tab('show') method is the one I copied when I referenced the TAB component of bootstrap.  I changed a browser to test the problem yesterday on the mobile phone and did not need to introduce jquery, but I do not know why the situation in the problem occurred

Answer (score 0):

You can check the order of adding js files as sometimes jquery conflict occurs with multiple inclusions or the wrong order of adding js files.

Comment: Strangely enough, I changed the browser on my phone and tested it without any problems, and I don't need to reference jquery anymore